# Croogo - admin menu shows error on live server

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, croogo

Iam working on croogo and i have achieved all the things.But unfortunately the admin menus toggle effect does not work when uploaded on live server.When checked console,Shows this error in admin.js at line 37. I searched and found the below code making issue:

```
var $sidebar = $('#sidebar-menu');
var $topLevelMenus = $('#sidebar-menu > li > .hasChild');

// no item is current, fallback to current controller index
var $current = $('.sidebar .current');
if ($current.length == 0) {
    var selector = _.template(
        "a.sidebar-item[href^='<%= basePath %>admin/ +
        <%= params.plugin %>/ +
        <%= params.controller %>']:first"
    );
    if ($(selector(Croogo)).addClass('current').length == 0) {
        var selector = _.template(
            'a.sidebar-item[href="<%= basePath %>admin/' +
            '<%= params.plugin %>"]'
        );
        $(selector(Croogo)).addClass('current');
    }
}
```

> Error Message : b>Notice (8): Use of undefined constant basePath - assumed 'basePath' [**APP/Plugin/Croogo/webroot/js/admin.js**, line **37**

This is my first project using croogo.Can anyone help me out with this issue.Thanks  in advance.

Comment: This works totally fine for me on my local systems..I tried many alternatives but in vain.Please help me.

Comment: looks like a bug of croogo, [report it here](http://croogo.lighthouseapp.com/projects/32818-croogo/overview)

Comment: I have created a ticket for this http://croogo.lighthouseapp.com/projects/32818-croogo/tickets/459  but it is marked as spam!!

Comment: screenshot of error message http://i.imgur.com/oUky3Y1.png

Comment: Yes..iam facing the same issue as subodh...thanks for the screenshot subodh

Comment: i just uploaded all my stuff on another server and it is working smoothly without any error.I dont know what was causing error.I guess it is server related issue. Anyways thank u all for reply.

Answer (score 3):

The php interpreter tries to parse a portion of javascript file as PHP. Try turning off php short tags.

Answer (score 0):

It is all because PHP configuration. On some configurations Notice Errors don't break the execution of code. But on some, mostly Linux configurations any error breaks execution. One of the cases is that there is some wrapper for JS files that adds error message to script and damage its syntax. Other case is that Notice message is sent before header is set and rest of code can't execute properly.

Most of those cases can be patched by adding this line to the first script executed:

```
error_reporting (0);
```

here is php documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

or in this particular case of CakePHP, in your **/app/Config/core.php** you can set

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

This should help.